# Deleting records with associations - cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm quite new in cakephp 3 and I don't really know how to do this.

I have a groups table and a users table, they have a relationship of group has many users.

What I 'm trying to do is, if I want to delete a group and said group has any user, then it can't be deleted. The group can only be deleted if it's empty.

I just started with cakephp a week ago and I'm quite lost with this, so I would really appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a count on the number of users in a group and if it is 0 delete it and if not don't

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users'); //or simply use $this->loadModal('Users');

//asuming the Users table has a group_id to identify the group
$query = $users->findByGroupId('id_of_the_group_you_wanna_delete')->count();
    if ($query === 0) {
        //delete group
    } else {
        //show warning not able to delete group
    }
```

be sure to check out ndm's comment below about transactions and/or foreign key constraints

Comment: What you are doing there is counting the groups, that would result in no groups ever being deleted ;)

Comment: ty for paying attention ndm, I changed my answer:)

Comment: You're welcome, please take my upvote ;) btw, I think it should be noted that this is best being done in a transaction, or with additional foreign key constraints to prevent the delete operation on DB level.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you both for helping me, this solved my problem.